# Postgresql Top N items from a group WHERE N is variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine a table of fruit graded on a scale of 1 to 10.

```
id, fruit, grade
1, Apple, 1
2, Orange, 5
3, Apple, 4
4, Apple, 7
5, Orange, 4
```

And an order table:

```
order_id, item, quantity
10, apple, 2
10, orange 1
```

A query for  order #10 tells me tells me I need to ship 2 apples, and 1 orange.

Is there a way to join / group the order and fruit table for the ids of the 2 best apples and the 1 best orange, such as the result with the table above would be: 1,3,5 ?

```
result_table
order, fruit_id
10, 1
10, 3
10, 5
```

I feel confident I could figure out how to return a static number from each group, but a variable count from each group is stumping me. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will be able to use `row_number()` to achieve this:

```
with f as (
  select
    id fruit_id,
    fruit,
    row_number() over (partition by fruit order by grade) rn
  from
    fruit
)
select
  o.order_id,
  f.fruit_id
from
  f
    inner join
  "order" o
    on o.item = f.fruit
where
  f.rn <= o.quantity
```

Naming a table after a sql keyword (order) might not be the best idea.

Here's an [Exaple SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5c17b/2). Note I had to use `lower` to compare fruit with item as the cases in the example differ. I'm not sure whether Postgres offers case insensitive collations.

Comment: Very good! Now I can launch my successful career as a fruit distributor! (Of course my real problem has nothing to do with fruit, but your solution abstracts perfectly).

Comment: For what it's worth, Postgres provides a case-insensitive string type in the [`citext`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/citext.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

```
select order_id, fruit_id
  from (select order_id,
               f.id as fruit_id,
               f.grade,
               o.quantity,
               row_number() over(partition by f.fruit order by f.grade) as rn
          from "order" o
          join fruit f
            on o.item = f.fruit) x
 where quantity >= rn
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/caf4d/1/0